# Sequence of numbers from 1 to 100 in a List in Mulesoft

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have a list with a sequence like #[[1,2,3,4]. I want to define another list with sequence of numbers from 1 to 100. I tried to use #[[1..100]] but this is not allowed. How can i achieve this in mulesoft ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mule 4 and dataweave 2 `..` operator is used for different use-case now. For a range use `to` instead:

```
#[1 to 100]
```

In mule 3 and dataweave 2, use .. but if you want it as an inline expression, you need to wrap it in `dw` function

```
    #[dw('[1..100]', 'application/java')]
```

Or use the the transform-message component for non inline transforms

Comment: This doesn't work for Mule 3. How can i do this Mule 3?

Comment: Uodated for mule 3/dw1

Comment: Don't the surrounding square braces wrap the range in an additional array? Resulting in `[[1,2,3,...]]`

Comment: Right, I wrapped it in an array as the question example had theirs wrapped in array. But yeah it’s redundant. I’ll edit it.

Comment: How can this be done in mule 3, dw 1? I tried this #[dw('(1..100)', 'application/java')]"  i got Execution of the expression failed

Comment: fixed. you need the square braces in dw 1.

Answer (score 0):

Although one can simply use the range operator `to` to generate a big list of numbers. There are still other ways to attain this, especially by using lambda variables turned functions.

To generate numbers starting from 1, we can try a recursive function call as given below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var nums = (k: Number, arr: Array<Number>=[]) -> if(k > 0) nums(k-1, (arr + k)) else arr[-1 to 0]
---
nums(4)
```

To generate numbers based on a starting and ending range; try the below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var nums = (j, k: Number, arr: Array<Number>=[]) -> if(k > (j-1)) nums(j,k-1, (arr + k)) else arr[-1 to 0]
---
nums(7, 11)
```